# Problemas con insercion mysql desde php por caracteres utf-8

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Mi HTML y los llamados que hago a mi BD tienen carácteres especiales, pero cuando intento setear una tabla en mi base de datos con caracteres de este tipo me arroja cosas de este estilo `ObservaciÃƒÂ³n`

Mi html cuenta en el head con esto:

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

en php ya probe con:

```php
$comment = utf8_encode(isset($_POST['Observation'])?$_POST["Observation"]:'');
```

```php
$comment = utf8_decode(isset($_POST['Observation'])?$_POST["Observation"]:'');
```

También tengo en el encabezado del php que realiza el insert

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

La información la envío con `JS`, a través de un `Ajax` a un documento `PHP` que se encarga de hacer el insert en cuestión.

De paso agradezco, me indiquen como se puede poner el código en estas preguntas en su respectivo formato, siempre alguien debe corregírmelo, pero recuerdo haberlo visto en la inducción de la plataforma o no en los documentos que leí.

Comment: Cuando formulas la pregunta, hay un botón en la esquina superior derecha del editor que muestra un signo de interrogación. Allí tienes la ayuda para dar formato.

Comment: Prueba pasando los datos a la variable de la siguiente manera: `$comment = isset($_POST['Observation']) ? utf8_decode($_POST["Observation"]) : '';`. Y para consultar y mostrar la información en la vista usas `utf8_encode(...)`

Comment: Hola, logré resolverlo, resulta que de alguna forma al poner el header en php para condificar y luego poner el utf8_decode lo que hacía era codificar carácteres ya codificados, no sé como explicarlo, pero de alguna forma usar el header y el encode generaba que codificara mal lo que ya se había codificado bien en el insert.